# Multiple checkboxes are checked when one checkbox is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, checkbox, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have this scenario. I want to add grades i.e. classes in a wing of the school. And at same time I wanna specify which subjects will a class have. Snapshot of this scenario is attached.[image]

In coding, First I get list of all subjects. Then I assign this subject array to each class. Now I want to check some subjects and uncheck some so that I can save subjects for each class. But when I check any subject, all subjects of at same index get checked. E.g. when I check mathematics for class 1, All mathematics checkboxes get checked. I know there is a problem in my coding. I really need your help guys. I'm attaching code too.

**Geting All Subjects**

```
 //get subjects
    $http.post($scope.ClassCTRLUrl + "/getsubjects")
        .success(function (responce) {
            $scope.subjectList=responce.data;
            for(var i=0;i<$scope.subjectList.length;i++){
                $scope.subjectList[i].model=false;
            }

            //get list of all classes
            $scope.getMasterclassList();
        })
```

**Get Classes**

```
/* get all classes */
$scope.getMasterclassList=function(){
    $http.post($scope.ClassCTRLUrl + "/getClasses")
        .success(function (responce) {
            $scope.classList=responce.data;
            for(var i=0;i<$scope.classList.length;i++){
                $scope.classList[i].check=false;

                //assign subjects to each class
                $scope.classList[i].subjects= $scope.subjectList;
            }
            console.log($scope.classList);
        })
}
```

**Front End code by using nested ng-repeat**

```
<tr ng-repeat="class in classList">

                    <td class="padding-top-12"><span ng-bind="($index+1)"></span></td>

                    <td>
                        <span ng-bind="class.class_name" style="float:left;"></span>
                    </td>

                    <td style="text-align: center;">
                        <span ng-repeat="subject in class.subjects ">
                            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="subject.model" ng-true-value="'1'" ng-false-value="'0'" ng-change="print(subject.subject_name)" ><span ng-bind="subject.subject_name"></span>
                        </span>
                    </td>

                    <td style="text-align:center;">
                        <label class="switch ">
                        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="class.check" ng-change="checkOption(class.check,classList.indexOf(class))">
                        <div class="slider round"></div>
                        </label>
                    </td>
                </tr>
```

**And the actual problem**

The problem snapshot is attached
[image]

Comment: can you create a demo

Comment: <input type="checkbox" ng-model="class.check" ng-change="checkOption(class.check,classList.indexOf(class))">, give different names for  each, this is the reason

Comment: @ÁlvaroTouzón u r using parent list i.e. class list. My question is about subject list

Comment: @sachilaranawaka i HAVE Aattached sanpshots. When I click one checkbox, all other checkboxes at same index get checked.

Comment: You can use $parentIndex to differentiate for same index of subjects. Classs $index will be $parentIndex for subjects.

Comment: can u edit the code? Since I have tried to do that but couldn't. @arunsahani